# Не удаляется unique и length у столбца

Tags: mysql, база-данных, nestjs, typeorm

Создал сущность `group` и указал ей в опции `unique: true` и `length: 20`, но после чего убрал данный параметр. После чего уникальность и длина столбца никуда не уходит. Даже создание новой БД не помогло.
При попытке создать запись не удовлетворяющую этим условиям, то получаю ошибку...
При запуске `start:dev` очищается title во всех строках и выдаёт ошибку

```
[Nest] 16482   - 24.12.2020, 16:06:08   [ExceptionHandler] ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '' for key 'groups.IDX_6b70c09fbdab1399c207d91f41' +2ms
QueryFailedError: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '' for key 'groups.IDX_6b70c09fbdab1399c207d91f41'
```

UPDATE: Создал новый столбец name. Удалил title из энтити. Удалил title из самой БД, т.к после рестарта он не пропал. Рестартнул - title вернулся...

UPDATE: После рестарта на несколько секунд поле становиться не уникальным, но через некоторое время история повторяется

UPDATE: `typeorm schema:sync` - после вызова появляется поле title. После отключения synchronize в ormconfig title всё равно появляется

Сущность `group`

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  OneToMany,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { VisitorEntity } from './visitor.entity';

@Entity('groups')
export class GroupEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string; // после обновления стало name: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @OneToMany(() => VisitorEntity, (visitor) => visitor.group)
  visitors: VisitorEntity[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

Тип данных в БД стоит `varchar(20)`

Comment: `typeorm schema:sync`?

Comment: в ormconfig synchronize стоит на true

Comment: и порт/имя бд там тоже правильные? у меня synchronize стоит false, я делаю это вручную (чтоб было время подумать), так что не знаю что даст synchronize: true

Comment: да, всё верное
typeorm schema:sync - после выполнения в терминале нашел это
columns dropped in groups: title
query: ALTER TABLE `groups` DROP COLUMN `title`
query: ALTER TABLE `groups` ADD `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL
query: ALTER TABLE `groups` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_6b70c09fbdab1399c207d91f41` (`title`)

Comment: @nörbörnën после того как выкачал репозиторий с гитхаба, то такой ошибки нет. Очень странная штука...

Comment: стало нагляднее. если typeorm создаёт title и уникальный индекс, значит в каком-то модуле это запрограммировано. может быть у вас было, например, два модуля с объявлением `class GroupEntity`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117649/discussion-between-alexander-chernykh-and-norbornen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка решилась выкачиванием репозитория с гитхаба.
До этого переименовывал все сущности с `Some` на `SomeEntity`. Видимо прошлая entity осталась в папке dist и при рестарте TypeORM и её мигрировал